# Jboss eap 6.4 custom module error

Tags: jboss6.x

I am creating a spring custom module.I have created the directory "org.springframework.spring" in modules directory.
 -> added the spring jars in main.
-> created module.xml as follows:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.springframework.spring">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-security-config-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar"/>    
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
    <module name="javax.api" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/> 
  </dependencies>
</module>

4. Created jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in web-inf as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.springframework.spring" export="true" meta-inf="export">
      <imports>
                        <include path="META-INF**"/>
                      <include path="org**"/>
                </imports>
        </module>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

5. But When i deploy my application I am getting following error:
StackTrace:     

21:50:28,629 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\deployments
21:50:28,639 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SpringApp -Module.war" (runtime-name: "SpringApp -Module.war")
21:50:29,189 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
21:50:29,200 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
21:50:29,210 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
21:50:29,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
21:50:29,440 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
21:50:30,960 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean in Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean (Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter from [Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 35 more

21:50:30,961 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy in Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean (Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter from [Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 35 more

21:50:30,981 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringApp -Module.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringApp -Module.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SpringApp -Module.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean (Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter from [Module "org.springframework.spring:main" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 35 more

21:50:30,991 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SpringApp -Module.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringApp -Module.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringApp -Module.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"SpringApp -Module.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean (Module \"org.springframework.spring:main\" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\\Program Files\\jboss-eap-6.4\\modules,C:\\Program Files\\jboss-eap-6.4\\modules\\system\\layers\\base)))
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter from [Module \"org.springframework.spring:main\" from local module loader @eafc191 (finder: local module finder @612fc6eb (roots: C:\\Program Files\\jboss-eap-6.4\\modules,C:\\Program Files\\jboss-eap-6.4\\modules\\system\\layers\\base))]"}}
21:50:31,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS015859: Deployed "SpringApp -Module.war" (runtime-name : "SpringApp -Module.war")
21:50:31,141 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringApp -Module.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringApp -Module.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SpringApp -Module.war"

21:50:31,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
21:50:31,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
21:50:31,251 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) started (with errors) in 6833ms - Started 167 of 206 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 59 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
21:50:31,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SpringApp -Module.war (runtime-name: SpringApp -Module.war) in 143ms
21:50:31,681 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015858: Undeployed "SpringApp -Module.war" (runtime-name: "SpringApp -Module.war")
21:50:31,681 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringApp -Module.war".POST_MODULE

21:50:36,217 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found SpringApp -Module.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called SpringApp -Module.war.dodeploy
```

I am defining the module properly still it is not able to find.What can be the error?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError's  like this one are almost always the result of conflicting versions of servlet-api.jar--typically between your WEB-INF\lib and Spring's lib folder. Make sure you don't have servlet-api.jar in WEB-INF\lib by setting the appropriate scope in your build tool.

Comment: Add this to your pom.xml, replace the version with any latest stable version. search for spring-web in mvnrepository.com and get the latest version:::                                         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Thank you.This is working fine after removing the servlet-api.jar. Could you help me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626992/datasource-encryption-in-jboss-eap-6