# Datasource encryption in jboss eap 6

Tags: jboss6.x

I have encrypted the datasource as follows:

Standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc.com:1001:DEV1</connection-url>
<driver>oracle</driver>
<security>
<security-domain>encrypted-ds</security-domain>
</security>   
<validation>
<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
<background-validation>false</background-validation>
<stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
</validation>
</datasource>
```

->added the security-domain in security-domains tag:

```
<security-domain name="encrypted-ds" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
<login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
<module-option name="username" value="308c162f7c2ec7f"/>
<module-option name="password" value="308c162f7c2ec7f"/>
<module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=OracleDS"/>
</login-module>
</authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I want the username password to be plain text / '*'(in case of password) in management console.
Is it possible. ?? Any other encryption technique that I can use to do the same??

Answer (score 2):

In Jboss EAP 6 you can use the SecureIdentityLoginModule to add an encrypted password domain. For instance, you can define a security domain in standalone.xml or domain.xml:

```
<security-domain name="EncryptedPassword">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="SecureIdentity" flag="required">
      <module-option name="username" value="test"/>
      <module-option name="password" value="encrypted_password"/>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Then you can add this security domain in your particular data source that uses this userid/pwd combination in standalone.xml or domain.xml:

```
 <datasource ... >
       .....
       <security>
              <security-domain>EncryptedPassword</security-domain>
       </security>
  </datasource>
```

To encrypt the password itself, you can run this command (please verify the versions of picketbox jar and logging jar in your particular AS7 download to substitute accordingly):

```
java -cp $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.0.6.<beta|final>.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.1.0.<some_version>.jar:$CLASSPATH org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule password
```

This will return an encrypted password back that you can use in your security domain.

You can read more about JBoss AS7 security subsystem [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Security+subsystem+configuration)

Since open source rocks, you can see how the encoding code works in the source code of [SecureIdentityLogin](http://source.jboss.org/browse/PicketBox/trunk/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/picketbox/datasource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java?r=276). You will notice in the source code that it uses Blowfish for encryption.

Comment: I have done the same way. But the management console UI shows encrypted password like this '308c162f7c2ec7f' .It wont show the decrypted fomat.

Comment: Everything you need to know can be found in https://source.jboss.org/browse/PicketBox/trunk/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/picketbox/datasource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java?r=276  and https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Security+subsystem+configuration

Comment: I have implemented it this way,using security domain.There is no information about adding Datasource from management console UI and encryption of it. :(

Comment: Hi Anup...Can I extend SecureIdentityLoginModule and use my own encryption??